# Html table cells don't align properly

Tags: html, html-table

I can't understand why doesn't this table align properly. There are 9 pictures in first row, and 3 pictures in the second row. For some reason this table stretches beyond what is necessary, and produces gaps between the pictures. The width of the table is 990 and sum of widths of all the pictures for each row is also 990 (I don't count border width here, I just included it to show where the cells separate. The gap between the pictures is so large that it can not be explained by the border width).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body bgcolor="#008000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" >
<table id="Table_01" width="990" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_02.jpg" width="90" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_03.jpg" width="102" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_04.jpg" width="112" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="images/index_05.jpg" width="120" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_07.jpg" width="120" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="images/index_06.jpg" width="112" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_07.jpg" width="120" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_08.jpg" width="134" height="52" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_09.jpg" width="80" height="52" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><img src="images/index_11.jpg" width="346"/></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="images/index_12.jpg" width="308"/></td>
            <td colspan="4"><img src="images/index_13.jpg" width="336"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it looks. I made page background color to be green, so that it can be easily separated from images :

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use tables for layout of non tabulated data.  I'll try to give you a better example below in CSS with divs.

Comment: @thenetimp Maybe, but what is the problem with this particular case? I am just trying to make some changes to existing website which was built this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a css file that contains the following code and link it to your table.

```
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This should work for getting rid of the padding and margins in your table

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

**css**

```
body { font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana; }
.header ul li { background: url('tab-left.png') bottom left no-repeat; float:left; list-style:none; }
.header ul li a { background: url('tab-right.png') bottom right no-repeat; color:#fff; display:block; padding:10px 26px; text-decoration:none; }
.header ul li a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }

.sub-header { clear:both; }
.sub-header li { background: url('...'); }
.sub-header li a { background: url('...'); font-size:12pt; text-transform:uppercase; }
```

**html**

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coordinates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sub-header">
        <li><a href="#">Need Staff?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Looking for a job?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something....</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**images**

[image] and 
[image]

**result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's my code of how I would lay this out with HTML with a little CSS to try to help put you on the path to being current with your HTML skills.

I'm going to start with your background image.  Currently you have it as part if your images that you are piecing together in the table.  If you have syntax errors in your code, this can lead to misalignment like what you are seeing.  If instead you defined it as the background image of the body, this would never occur.

Next is the navigation.  You have a bunch of tabs.  These tabs include part of the background when they should really only be the images themselves.  A navigation is a list of webpages, so in essence you should use an unordered list, because they are in no particular order.  the css selector display: inline;  tells the list's line item to change it's display type so all the images float next to each other instead of being listed down from each other.  in the .nav class the margin tells it to center it, and the width is self explanatory.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-image: url('/images/background-image.png') repeat-y; }
        .nav { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
        .nav li { display: inline }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="header-nav nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="other-nav nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

To fix the above you would need to remove all the colspans from the first row.  They are useless then have the colspans in the 2nd row equal no more and no less than the rowspans of the 1st row.  After doing that the problem with that is your images don't add up mathematically so it'll be wrong.  You really need to recut your images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go CSS versions that people have posted.  Please don't perpetuate 1995 HTML....

However, to answer your original question, add up the widths you've specified.

```
<td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_02.jpg" width="90" height="52" /></td>
<td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_03.jpg" width="102" height="52" /></td>
<td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_04.jpg" width="112" height="52" /></td>
<td colspan="2"><img src="images/index_05.jpg" width="120" height="52" /></td>
```

Those columns correspond to a `colspan=4` group with a specified width of 346.  You'd be splitting the last column as it has a colspan of 2.  My head hurts already.

The second group is 3 columns:

```
<td colspan="1"><img src="images/index_07.jpg" width="120" height="52" /></td>
<td colspan="2"><img src="images/index_06.jpg" width="112" height="52" /></td>
```

Which add up to 232px.  The next corresponding row is `colspan=3` adding up to 308.  Since 308 != 232, you're going to have spaces.

Rinse and repeat for the next columns.  If you make the first row match up with the columns from the second row, your spaces go away.  If I was to do this (which I wouldn't) I would just have one row and one big column with all buttons in it.....

Answer (score 0):

Do not split the 2nd `tr` into 3 `td`s.

Just make 1 `td` in the 2nd `tr` and make it be `td colspan='9'`

I would also recommend not even doing 9 `td`s in the 1st `<tr>` because it's redundant (the images will "push" the boundaries of the table to fit their specs, regardless of `td` height/width settings.